# Type two objects to ensure they do not share any keys

Tags: typescript, types

I'd like to write a function of two arguments, each of which is an object.  These objects must not share keys. How do I type this constraint?

```js
// helpers
const a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4;

// how do I type this function?
function func(x, y) {/*...*/}

func({a, b, c}, {d}) // ok; no keys are shared
func({a, b}, {b, c}) // Error; key `b` is shared.
```

Alternatively posed: how do I constrain a type so that it does not contain keys of another type?

```
const foo = {a, b};
type X = typeof foo;
type NoKeysOf<S> = {/*... */}; // <- How do I constrin this type?
const bar: NoKeysOf<X> = {d};   // ok; no keys shared
const baz: NoKeysOf<X> = {b, c} // Error; `b` is shared
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enforce this kind of constraint at compile-time with the [never](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never) type.

```
declare function f<
  A,
  B extends { [K in keyof B]: K extends keyof A ? never : B[K] }
>(
  a: A, b: B
): any
```

What we are saying here is that if `K`, which is a key of `B`, extends one of the keys of `A`, its corresponding value in `b` will be of type `never` (hence, you could never construct it), otherwise, it'll just be `B[K]`.

And this has exactly the desired behaviour:

```
const a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4;
f({ a, b, c }, { d }) // OK
f({ a, b }, { b, c }) // Error: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=11&ssc=51&pln=8&pc=1#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtVIB4AoeeAQQBoT4AheEADwxFWAGd4BveAbQGl4WfAGsQATxyJaAXQBc8AY2asOoiVLLwA-PFQgAbiBjx5NftPgBfIgD4AFNSjzK8AEamiASnlRUYokRgeGwY8FDwALzwAIwUbpHwAExxYAkAzHHACQAsANwBiHbcUHGuKVZx3FmWnvAA9HXwOMK5ujjwahywCGwAFt3ARIXFpRVcbuU19Y0AojAwODCtavAABq6rghx9AwB0QA)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would write a function `findSameKeys` that returns all shared keys. It's up to you to also move the logic that follows into this function.

```js
function findSameKeys(x, y) {
  const xKeys = Object.keys(x);
  return Object.keys(y).filter(k => xKeys.includes(k));
}

const o1 = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
const o2 = { x: 1, y: 2, z: 3 };
const sameKeys = findSameKeys(o1, o2);
if (sameKeys.length === 0) {
   console.log('OK: no keys are shared');
} else {
   const verb = sameKeys.length === 1 ? ' is ' : ' are ';
   console.log('Error: keys ' + sameKeys + verb + 'shared');
}
```

Comment: The OP would like that check to be done at compile-time, not at runtime.

Comment: I'm afraid the above comment is correct. I'm writing a stub for someone else's global function and don't have the option of altering the runtime logic.